# Load Image From File and set into UnityEngine.UI.Image Unity

Tags: file-io, unity-game-engine

I try to load image from file and set into **UnityEngine.UI.Image**. the image is **BirdDiedScreenShot.PNG**. also define namespace

```
using System.IO;
```

But the problem is when i define path of image, Like

`byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (Application.persistentDataPath + "/BirdDiedScreenShot.png");`

in Above Code **ReadAllBytes()** method of **File** Class is not Work. It Give me Error like

> `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for`ReadAllBytes'

What's the problem i don't Solve.  how can i Fix This.? Please Give Me Suggestion to Solve this.. thanks...

Comment: Did you write Using or is it a copy & paste error? Because it needs to start with a lowercase u -> using.

Comment: No in a Script i write using in lowercase . #Wipster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with having "Web Player" selected as target platform.

When you click "File -> BuildSettings" in the Unity editor you see a little Unity icon next to the target platform. Switch to "PC, Mac & Linux Standalone" for example.

If you don't have the "PC, Mac & Linux Standalone" module loaded, check this thread: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-3-released.372567/page-2#post-2414948

By the way, the actual name of the Windows module is called "Windows Build Support".

In the new Download Assistant you can choose which modules to install. (Can be found on Unitys download page http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download?ref=personal)

greetings

Comment: Thanks.. #Wipster  . That's Work. i change my Default platform as a Android and Solve the problem...that is platform issue nothing else.